# Filter distinct rows based on the td text using jquery?

Tags: java, jquery

I have a loop in my jsp as shown below:

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <th>Region</th>
   <th>Locations</th>
  </tr>
   <c:forEach var="LocationBean" items="${list}">
    <tr>
    <td>${LocationBean.region_name}</td>
    <td>${LocationBean.location_name}</td>
 </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

which gives results something like this:
[image: results]

I need to get only distinct region name,I am very basic to jquery.

Comment: for example, what kind of value would you want to get for the table you provided?

Comment: I need to get region1 to be displayed only once.

Comment: I have another region2 with multiple location under that

Comment: all I need is to display unique region names

Comment: hmm, it sounds like you need to alter the `list` that you are iterating over, so that it only includes one item under each region

Comment: Yes Is it possible, I am very basic.

Comment: It would be better to use Map<String, String[]> or Map <String, List<String>>. Since Map will have distinct keys and you can put Multiple values for single key inside the map. hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must assign an id to the table like `mytable` and then use jquery filter method

```js
var uniqueItems = [];
$("#btn").on('click', function() {
  $("#list td")
    .filter(function(index, element) {
      if ($.inArray($(element).text(), uniqueItems) === -1) {
        uniqueItems.push($(element).text());
      } else {
        $(element).parent().remove();
      }

    });
  uniqueItems = [];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a href="#." class="btn btn-success" id="btn">Filter duplicate</a>
<table id="list" class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Region</th>
    <th>Locations</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>EAST</td>
    <td>loc1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>EAST</td>
    <td>loc1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North</td>
    <td>loc2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>West</td>
    <td>loc3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the code: But how do I replace the result in my table: I mean I need to display as shown the attachment I have attached.like Region Name :region1      | loc1 loc2 loc3 and again region 2     | loc1 loc2 loc3

Comment: Hi Thanks for the code: But how do I replace the result in my table: I mean I need to display as shown the attachment I have attached.like Region Name :region1      | loc1 loc2 loc3 and again region 2     | loc1 loc2 loc3

Comment: wait a minute you said you want to get the distinct names? now you are saying you have to replace the table why are you populating the duplicated list why not filter it before in your server side rather than the client side? can you please add more detail to your question, why are you doing this, why are you not filtering the records/list before populating it

Comment: I have already mentioned that I am basic to these things. Please let me know that Is it possible to do ?

Comment: well atleast you should be able to describe your problem, anyway i have updated my code above see if that is how you want it to work i have added a button which will remove the duplicate rows from a table. you can copy the required snippet to your section

Comment: Hi thanks again I am not able to see your updated code

Comment: refresh the page and click the run code snippet button